# how to lock login terminal on a server

Tags: command-line, server, bash, login, lock-screen

is there a way to lock a login console of a server after a certain time of inactivity? just lock; not log the user out.

if found [`vlock`](https://www.tecmint.com/vlock-lock-user-virtual-console-terminal-linux/) (and [`physlock`](https://github.com/muennich/physlock)) that seems to do a decent job of locking the login session. but is there a way to invoke it after a given time of user inactivity? i only can invoke it *right now* and its timeout flag does not seem to do what i need.

[this](https://wroot.org/posts/terminal-auto-lock-with-zsh-and-vlock/) seems to be a way on how to do it in `zsh`; but i'd need something in `bash`.

also note: i am not concerned about `ssh` sessions. and this is about servers (without any `X` installed).

**UPDATE** i know about `TMOUT`. i do not want to log the user out, i just want to lock their screen.

(also posted the question over at [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/questions/958232/how-to-lock-login-terminal-on-a-server))

Answer (score 1):

You can append the following line to `~/.bashrc` or `/etc/bash.bashrc` (to apply it for all user):

```
TMOUT=120
```

Then `source ~/.bashrc` or open new login shell and after 120 seconds of inactivity it will be closed. Note the login shell could be a hardware TTY/console or ssh connection, or some GIU terminal emulator as *gnome-terminal*, etc.

Source:

- [OSTechNix: How To Auto Logout Inactive Users After A Period Of Time In Linux](https://www.ostechnix.com/auto-logout-inactive-users-period-time-linux/)

Comment: ah, sorry, forgot to mention that i do not want `TMOUT` as that logs the user out. e.g. all `byobu` sessions are lost. that is not suitable for my use case... sorry! but thanks for the reply! +1. (`TMOUT` is already mentioned in the link...)